# Use Entity Framework and dynamically connect to a third party database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on an application where the ui may connect to multiple databases. Some of these databases have static schema. Others need to be queried based on schema provided by the admin (dynamically).

I want to be able to use the features of Entity Framework when working on the static databases and somehow use ADO.Net for the dynamic databases.

Also there is a possibility that a static db has 90% expected schema but few tables are generated dynamically. So I want Entity Framework to just work with the models I have defined. I dont want it to crib about the dynamic tables which got generated.

Is there a way ? Am I making sense ?

Comment: May be use dapper or plain old ado.net to run dynamic queries. for static models its okay to use EF perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer this [link](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) and its too complex to map EF runtime so its better to go with ado on dynamic things and try to put static things in EF.